# Override image-formatter.html.twig

Tags: 8, entities

I'm looking for an option to override the `image-formatter.html.twig` template in my own theme. But in the HTML page output (twig debug is set to `true`) there's no option listed to override the formatter template. The only thing I see is:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/image/templates/image-formatter.html.twig' -->
```

I need to place a `rel` attribute for the link which surrounds the image.

I found a solution which uses the option that you can write your own field formatter in your own module. But that seems to be too complex for this simple task.

Comment: That debug output doesn't mean you can't override the template, it just means there are no additional/more specific template suggestions. You may be able to add your own suggestion to meet this use case. I can try to write up an answer showing how to do that if that sounds helpful but the granularity may be somewhat limited. For example within this context we probably don't know what the image field is called but we do know the image style. If you want to add `rel` to all image formatter output it's a simple template override.

Comment: Thx for your comment. Yes that sounds helpful. I like to override the template for a specific node type and a specific field in those nodes. So I can use something like `field-formatter--node--mynode--my-field.html.twig`?

Answer (score 15):

In your [.theme file](https://www.drupal.org/node/2349803#theme), add this [suggestions alter hook](https://www.drupal.org/node/2100775) (and flush caches so the new hook definition is picked up):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_image_formatter_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $entity = $variables['item']->getEntity();
  $field_name = $variables['item']->getParent()->getName();
  $suggestions[] = 'image_formatter__' . $entity->getEntityTypeId() . '__' . $entity->bundle() . '__' . $field_name;
}
```

Then if you look at the [twig_debug output](https://www.drupal.org/node/2358785), you should see something like:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * image-formatter--node--article--field-image.html.twig
   x image-formatter.html.twig
-->
```

Once that is done, you can create your template file called `image-formatter--node--article--field-image.html.twig` in the templates directory of your theme, flush caches again so the template is picked up, and override the template with any changes you'd like.

This should include a caveat that the code hasn't been thoroughly tested :)