# Override Image Formatter template based on parent view

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have multiple views for the same content type (article), and want to override the Image Formatter template based on the view that is rendering it.

I have been able to add a suggestion to `theme_suggestions_image_formatter_alter` and select a template based on the content type and field name, based on the answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/141340/12336), but if I apply that to the image field inside the article type, that applies to all views of this type. Is there any way to extract the view information inside the `alter` function so I can select the template based on the view as well as the content type?

Comment: You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode to create different variation of node display and use it based on your requirements.

Comment: That project is only for Durpal 7, but it lead me to https://www.drupal.org/project/ds which looks promising, I'll give it a shot and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were using D7. Anyway DS should be able to handle this and much more.